# Uploading an image from python client to a flask server

Tags: python, image, http, flask, python-requests

I am using `requests` and `requests_toolbelt` to send an image to the cloud and so far I have something like this

```
import requests
import json
from requests_toolbelt import MultipartEncoder

m = MultipartEncoder(
    fields={"user_name":"tom", "password":"tom", "method":"login",
            "location":"landing", "cam_id":"c00001", "datetime":"hammaTime!"
            ,'image': ('filename', open('image.jpg', 'rb'))}
    )
r = requests.post(url, data=m)
print r.text
```

After it gets to the server, how to I get back a dictionary of something usable? The [toolbelt docs](http://toolbelt.readthedocs.org/en/latest/user.html#streaming-multipart-data-encoder)  show only how to post, not how to handle it on the other end. Any advice?

Comment: Did you look at the [Flask Quickstart](https://flask.readthedocs.org/en/latest/quickstart/) yet? It handles how to access request data, including uploaded files.

Comment: @MartijnPieters there's also a really valuable section about Uploading Files that I linked to in my answer. The quick start is good, but if OP is storing files on anyone's behalf they should read the full documentation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can see a working example of Flask server which accepts POSTS like the on you're trying to make on [HTTPbin](https://httpbin.org/). If you do something like:

```
m = MultipartEncoder(fields=your_fields)
r = requests.post('https://httpbin.org/post', data=m, headers={'Content-Type': m.content_type})
print(r.json()['form'])
```

You'll see that everything in your post should be in that dictionary.

Using HTTPBin's source, you can then see that the `form` section is generated from `request.form`. You can use that to retrieve the rest of your data. Then you can use `request.files` to access the image you wish to upload.

The example Flask route handler would look like:

```
@app.route('/upload', methods=['POST'])
def upload_files():
    resp = flask.make_response()
    if authenticate_user(request.form):
        request.files['image'].save('path/to/file.jpg')
        resp.status_code = 204
    else:
        resp.status_code = 411
    return resp
```

You should read into [Uploading Files](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/patterns/fileuploads/?highlight=upload%20file) documentation though. It is really invaluable when using common patterns like this in Flask.

Answer (score 1):

`requests-toolbelt` can only send the file to the server but it is up to you to save that on the server side and then return meaningful result. You can create a flask endpoint to handle the file upload, return the desired result dictionary as a JSON and then convert the JSON back to dict on the client side with `json.loads`.

```
@app.route('/upload', methods=['POST'])
def upload_file():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        f = request.files['image']
        f.save('uploads/uploaded_file')
        # do other stuff with values in request.form
        # and return desired output in JSON format
        return jsonify({'success': True})
```

See flask [documentation](https://flask.readthedocs.org/en/latest/quickstart/#file-uploads) for more info on file uploading.

Also, you need to specify the mime-type while including the image in `MultipartEncoder` and content-type in the header while making the request. (I'm not sure you if you can even upload images with MultipartEncoder. I was successful with only the text files.)

```
m = MultipartEncoder(
    fields={"user_name":"tom", "password":"tom", "method":"login",
            "location":"landing", "cam_id":"c00001", "datetime":"hammaTime!"
            ,'image': ('filename', open('file.txt', 'rb'), 'text/plain')}  # added mime-type here
    )
r = requests.post(url, data=m, headers={'Content-Type': m.content_type})  # added content-type header here
```